# Raspberry Pi running OpenVPN (client) behind Router running OpenVPN (server) can't access any ports

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi

When I'm connected over Wi-Fi, my Raspberry Pi is fine and dandy I can connect to it over ssh, web server is working correctly, i.e. I can access 192.168.0.2:80 and it works. (This is without any VPNs)

Then I run OpenVPN server on the router. I connect from a different network, and everything is still fine. I can connect to the Pi like I was at home.

The problem happens when I run an OpenVPN client on the Pi. I cannot SSH **into** the Pi, web servers are not accessible etc.

How to fix this?

**More about OpenVPN configuration**
(I will focus on the Pi, since only when openvpn runs on it problems begin):

`OpenVPN 2.4.7 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`
I run OpenVPN through `systemd` by creating a `client.conf` in `/etc/openvpn`:
Here's that stripped down [client.conf gist](https://gist.github.com/JakubKoralewski/21398b262c043a80af12d11e3da37ba0)).

Here's [the output](https://gist.github.com/JakubKoralewski/4dca4ccaf427974c6156c270eeb9c681) of `sudo systemctl show openvpn@client`.

Here's `ifconfig` of `tun0`:

```
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.38.10.6  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.38.10.5
        inet6 fe80::8fc8:3f92:1b5f:18ed  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 9  bytes 958 (958.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22  bytes 1539 (1.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here's a routing table from the router:

[image: routing table]

Comment: Tell us more about the OpenVPN configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound I added some more info. It's a shot in the dark really so probably not much. I think some `iptables` config is needed, but I have no idea how and why to use what commands.

Comment: Please tell me if I can supply some more different more pertinent information, cause I'm shooting blind.

Comment: @Ramhound I've added a routing table from the router, I dunno if that'll help.